# what happens when the executing process is interrupted before its time slice by an I/O in round robin

Tags: operating-system, scheduling

In round robin scheduling policy, suppose a process is running, and it's interrupted before its time slice ( the time which CPU is giving to every process) then what will happen?

example :

```
time slice : 3 ms .
P1 executes for 2 ms , and is interrupted ...
P2 starts ...
```

Question is when P1 comes next time for execution whether it will be given 3 ms or 4ms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when a process is interrupted before it's time slice :
Interruption can mean in 2 ways :
1) may be requiring `I/O` , so goes to `waiting` queue , CPU can execute another process.
2) may `terminate` due to an error , so is killed

In both cases , new process starts with it's time starting from 0 , example :
`time slice` : `3 ms` .
`P1` executes for `2 ms` , and is interrupted ...
Now at t= `2ms` , `P2` starts executing and if it goes on smoothly , it wil be given `3ms` .

**EDIT**
no , it will be given 3 ms only , may be after P2 is over , CPU may execute P3 and after I/O is done by P1 , it may go to ready queue , so next time CPU execute P1 , it gives it 3ms .

Comment: 1) Since this process is not given time as it should have been given, so will this left time be given to this process next time it comes for execution or it will be given exactly the time slice allocated?

Comment: and next time when p1 will come it will be given 3 ms or 4ms?

This is what my question is.

Comment: no , it will be given 3 ms only , may be after P2 is over , CPU may execute P3 and after I/O is done by P1 , it may fo to ready queue , so next time CPU execute P1 , it gives it 3ms .